# MYSQL Having with Or Statements

Tags: mysql, having

I am having a bit of trouble with a select statement. See my code, for brevity I removed unimportant elements.

```
   $sql = "SELECT … column names … (calculation for distance)… as distance 
   FROM table 
   WHERE col1 = 'value1' AND col2 = 'value2' HAVING distance < 1
```

The above code works perfectly fine. However, when I a attempt to add an OR statement because I want another column to search for multiple values there appears to be a conflict with the query. It works without HAVING clause but than I lose that search option if removed. I get an error that says it is no the right syntax when changed to code below.

```
   $sql = "SELECT … column names … (calculation for distance)… as distance 
   FROM table 
   WHERE col1 = 'value1' AND col2 = 'value2' HAVING distance < 1 
   OR col1 = 'value1' AND col2 = 'a different value' HAVING distance < 1
```

Any thoughts on this, I am not sure what the conflict would be. Perhaps there is a better way to search with an OR statement for multiple values for one column.

Comment: having should be used along with group by. Can u post some data in http://sqlfiddle.com and the expected result in the question.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty . . . The OP is using a MySQL extension that allows the `having` clause to reference column aliases.  This is perfectly normal in MySQL, although the resulting queries look a bit awkward to those who adhere closer to the standard.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for clarifying this. Just love SO learning a lot of thing in each question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The having by clause needs to be at the end

So

```
   $sql = "SELECT … column names … (calculation for distance)… as distance 
   FROM table 
   WHERE col1 = 'value1' AND col2 IN ('value2' , 'a different value')
   HAVING distance < 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give a good answer without a sqlfiddle or the entire sql query, but what about :

```
   SELECT … column names … (calculation for distance)… as distance 
   FROM table 
   WHERE (col1 = 'value1' AND col2 = 'value2' OR col1 = 'value1' AND col2 = 'a different value')
   HAVING distance < 1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, that was the fix. I was trying to use HAVING with the WHERE and subsequent OR statements individually. I have a little education to do with how to structure MYSQL statements still but this was extremely helpful. Thanks so much for your assistance.